# why am i unable to create a successful message loop with PeekMessage()?

Tags: loops, winapi, message

My guess it's somehow receiving a WM_QUIT message, because that is what the while loop revolves around ( which according to the proc function happens whenever a WM_DESTROY message is processed)

The window automatically closes whenever i use PeekMessage instead of GetMessage , Im using PeekMessage in order to run the loop at maximum speed

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MSG msg;
if(!CreateMainWindow(hinstance, nCmdShow))
   return false;
//this works
while (GetMessage(&msg, (HWND) NULL, 0 , 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return (int) msg.wParam;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
}    

//this automatically closes the window
int done = 0;
while (!done)
{
    if (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0 ,0, PM_REMOVE))
    {

        if (msg.message = WM_QUIT)
            done = 1;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
return msg.wParam;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
```

here's the simple WinProc function

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc ( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM   
lParam)
{
switch( msg)
{
      Case WM_DESTROY: 
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;
}
return DefWindowProc ( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, since you overwrote the question with the answer. Two answers without a question is not helpful to future visitors. Since you haven't done so, consider taking the [tour].

Comment: if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)

Comment: "*Im using PeekMessage in order to run the loop at maximum speed*" - what makes you think calling `PeekMessage()` in a loop is any faster than calling `GetMessage()` in a loop?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau PeekMessage() is faster than GetMessage() because GetMessage() waits for a message before returning

Comment: @hec: that does not mean anything. In the code you showed, calling `PeekMessage()` in a busy loop that doesn't do anything else while there are no messages to process is just going to peg the CPU endlessly and offers no benefit. At least `GetMessage()` will put the calling thread to sleep until a new message arrives.

Comment: in the context of the code yes, but as a beginner game programmer i am simply trying to make sense of the textbook im using , which is to use PeekMessage

i should take your suggestion tho, and use getmessage while the loop isn't doing anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are assigning WM_QUIT to msg.message instead of comparing it.

Comment: This is why you should always compile with warnings enabled.

Comment: ...or not ignore warnings!

That is also why sometimes it is recommended to do comparisons as rather: "if (WM_QUIT == msg.message)".  If you accidentally forget and code the comparison as assignment (== as =), then the compiler will issue an error.